# Problems with searching multiple line in REGEX

Tags: regex

So ive been trying to match different string in different line with regex(currently using editpadpro)

My problems:- i want to match (POLYLINE,Type,Road) **without matching with the type under POI**, consider that theres group POLYLINE AND POI, i just want to match whatever inside the POLYLINE

Example -

```
      POLYLINE
      Type=0x6
      Road=2231
     
      POI
      Type=0x64
```

Comment: In another word, i want to match with different string, because all i found on the internet usually have something in common for example number or rhymes which is easy but what about if i want to match Type=0xe and Road=1234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to use a combination of ***positive lookahead*** and ***positive lookbehind***:

```
(?<=POLYLINE\s)(?:\w+=\w+\s?)+(?=\s*[A-Z]+)?
```

With this regex, you say:

- `\w+=\w+` that is preceded by `POLYLINE` and that is succeded or not by something in uppercase (next section).

By this way, you can match every section as you want

```
(?<=SECTIONNAME\s)(?:\w+=\w+\s?)+(?=\s*[A-Z]+)?

POLYLINE
Type=0x6
Road=2231
     
POI
Type=0x64

ANOTHER
Road=456
```

Here [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/gIZVUj/2)